# GTK error when using opencv with python in ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, gtk

I am trying to follow a tutorial found [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html#calibration) to calibrate a camera via a chessboard image, using python and opencv in Ubuntu 18.04. Everything goes well until the program gets to the `cv2.imshow()` function, at which point I get the following error:

> Gtk-ERROR **: 19:31:06.612: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x
>   and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported Trace/breakpoint trap
>   (core dumped)

I can only get around this error by commenting out the function. As I am quite new to programming, I don't know how to troubleshoot this further. Searching for this error online shows it being encountered in scenarios different from mine. I would really appreciate any help in resolving this. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you're trying to load two different major versions of GTK in the same process—either because you're importing the Gtk module like:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

or because the OpenCV Python module is trying to side-load a GTK module by itself. Since OpenCV seems to use Qt, it might be a case of a GTK module being loaded in your environment to match the system's style.

Comment: I'm not importing Gtk myself, so it would have to be the latter. So the system uses Gtk 3.0, and opencv adds Gtk 2.0? Is there a way to check which is using which?

Comment: [GitHub Issue #6680](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6680)